# Value of global variable is changed inside of a function, but I cannot understand why it is happened

Tags: python, deep-learning, global-variables

While I study with "Deeplearning from scratch" and its example code, I see that value of global variable is changed inside of function.

I tried to understand this but failed. I hope someone tell me how this code works.

In detail, object "net.W" is changed after keyword "weight" what receives "net.W" in the function changed. I think "net.W" will be not changed because this is global variable without global. But this is changed and I can not under stand.

The code has been modified based on https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-from-scratch.

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np

class simpleNet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.W = np.random.rand(2,3)

    def predict(self, x):
        return np.dot(x, self.W)

    def loss(self, x, t):
        z = self.predict(x)
        z = np.sum(z)
        return z

def numerical_gradient(f, weight):
    h = 1.0
    grad = np.zeros_like(weight)

    it = np.nditer(weight, 
                   flags=['multi_index'], 
                   op_flags=['readwrite'])

    while not it.finished:
        idx = it.multi_index

        print("Before net.W: \n",net.W)

        weight[idx] = weight[idx] + h

        print("After net.W: \n",net.W)
        print(' ')
        it.iternext()

net = simpleNet()
print('Originla net.W: \n', net.W)
x = np.array([0.6, 0.9])
t = np.array([0,0,1])
dW = numerical_gradient(f, net.W)
```

I expected the printed "net.W" objects are same, but the component of  "net.W" is changed(+1.0 by h) every time after the keyword  "weight" is changed.

```
''''''
Originla net.W: 
[[0.74942285 0.28408918 0.43493956]
 [0.50182208 0.19556924 0.75924396]]
''''''

''''''
Before net.W: 
 [[0.74942285 0.28408918 0.43493956]
 [0.50182208 0.19556924 0.75924396]]
After net.W: 
 [[1.74942285 0.28408918 0.43493956]
 [0.50182208 0.19556924 0.75924396]]

Before net.W: 
 [[1.74942285 0.28408918 0.43493956]
 [0.50182208 0.19556924 0.75924396]]
After net.W: 
 [[1.74942285 1.28408918 0.43493956]
 [0.50182208 0.19556924 0.75924396]]

Before net.W: 
 [[1.74942285 1.28408918 0.43493956]
 [0.50182208 0.19556924 0.75924396]]
After net.W: 
 [[1.74942285 1.28408918 1.43493956]
 [0.50182208 0.19556924 0.75924396]]

Before net.W: 
 [[1.74942285 1.28408918 1.43493956]
 [0.50182208 0.19556924 0.75924396]]
After net.W: 
 [[1.74942285 1.28408918 1.43493956]
 [1.50182208 0.19556924 0.75924396]]

Before net.W: 
 [[1.74942285 1.28408918 1.43493956]
 [1.50182208 0.19556924 0.75924396]]
After net.W: 
 [[1.74942285 1.28408918 1.43493956]
 [1.50182208 1.19556924 0.75924396]]

Before net.W: 
 [[1.74942285 1.28408918 1.43493956]
 [1.50182208 1.19556924 0.75924396]]
After net.W: 
 [[1.74942285 1.28408918 1.43493956]
 [1.50182208 1.19556924 1.75924396]]
''''''
```

Comment: Not sure if it makes a good dupe, but this is closely related: [Function modifies list](//stackoverflow.com/q/49395467)

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks a lot! I understand this with your recommend post now. I've never expected that arguments in function is shallow copy.

Comment: Function arguments aren't copied at all.